# Error while Downloading Android Source code

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-source, repo

I am trying to download the android source code and for that I am following official documents provided on source.android.com, using command :-

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-5.0.0_r1
```

or

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
```

but I am getting following error :-

```
fatal: Cannot get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/clone.bundle
fatal: error [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

I am not able to figure out where I am doing it wrong !!
any lead is appreciated.

**Update**

I went ahead with following command :-

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.4_r1
```

and then executed `repo sync` , everything was working fine but at last i got this error :-

```
100 10.8G  100 10.8G    0     0   259k      0 12:12:36 12:12:36 --:--:--  895k
remote: Sending approximately 10.88 GiB ...
remote: Counting objects: 46, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (40/40)
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200 | 915.00 KiB/s      
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
remote: Sending approximately 10.88 GiB ...
remote: Counting objects: 46, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (40/40)
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200 | 881.00 KiB/s      
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
error: Cannot fetch device/lge/hammerhead-kernel
```

any lead on this is appreciated !!

Comment: The error message indicates that Repo can't look up the hostname. Does `host gerrit.googlesource.com`, `dig gerrit.googlesource.com`, or `nslookup gerrit.googlesource.com` work and return at least one IP address?

Comment: i ran the host command here is the o/p 
 host gerrit.googlesource.com
gerrit.googlesource.com has address 173.194.67.82

Comment: @MagnusBäck please check my update also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There have been 4 commits to git-repo just a few hours ago, all regarding clone.bundle cookies, except the first of those. If your problem is still going on, use the stable branch, which is before today's commits. I setup a server yesterday, so I know it works fine. The last commit, before those 4 was from 12 days ago. In order to use a specific branch, tag, or commit you use --repo-branch and you can also use --repo-url to download git-repo from another website, but you shouldn't need that, just do this to use the version before today's commits. First make sure you remove any bad or problem version and partial info, by removing the `.repo` subdirectory from your working directory, by running:

`rm -rf .repo`

Then run:

`repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-5.0.2_r1 --repo-branch stable`

Comment: i m getting this erro :- 
fatal: branch 'c8d882ae2a75c732ef590ef425a3039b8b04403e' has not been signed

Comment: fatal: refs/remotes/origin/c8d882ae2a75c732ef590ef425a3039b8b04403e^0: not a valid SHA1

Comment: not working :-
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Server does not provide clone.bundle; ignoring.
fatal: remote error: Git repository not found
ssh: Could not resolve hostname https: Name or service not known
fatal: remote error: Git repository not found
fatal: cannot obtain manifest https://android.googlesource.com

Comment: okay its working now :-
repo has been initialized in /home/rajiv/aosp
thanks :) , can u tell we what is the size of complete source after downloading and how much time its gonna take ?

Comment: and does it contains complete source ?

Comment: i am following u on git-hub , is there any other way to contact u , like any chat service or something